# how to access object value in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I want to access object value(i.e rulenames-decline,postpone,warning...) in checkbox, using ng-repeat and also display checkbox as checked when value in object is 'Y' and unchecked when value is 'N'

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="rules in savedRulesData ">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxed" value="{{savedRulesData}}">{{rules}}
</label>
</div>
```

Currently my checkbox is displayed as illustrated in image.

I open this model using editRules Function in my controller

[http://tinypic.com/r/fog2gk/9] Image link

```
$scope.editRules = function(ruleTypes,client) {
        var obj=new Object();
        var self=this;
        var clientId=client.clientId;

        var responsePromise = $http.get("typesofSavedRules/"+clientId);
        responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            self.savedRulesData=data.objList;   
            $scope.savedRulesData=self.savedRulesData;
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("AJAX failed!");
        });

        modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            scope: $scope,
            size:'lg'
        });
    };
```

Comment: what is the structure of `savedRulesData `? btw you can use  [`ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: It is an object you can see it in image link @pro.mean

Comment: Tip: there must be unique id on one page. and write `ng-model` in checkbox

Comment: what is that object structure? because you are trying to consume value from the object in order to make checkbox as selected/unselected right.?

Comment: paste object structure within question

Comment: savedRulesData is currently dispalyed as a single checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ng-checked="{{expression}}"` like -

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="rules in savedRulesData ">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxed" ng-checked="{{rules.rule=='Y'}}">{{rules}}
</label>
</div>
```

Just have the correct property of the `rules` object.

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed. But i am trying to access rules object though ng-model="rules" in my controller  because i want to save rules which get checked and then property rules[1]=='Y' of unchecked rules changes to 'Y'. But i am not able to access rules object in my controller by scope variable i.e $scope.rule;

Answer (score 0):

Do as following,

```
<div ng-repeat="value in savedRulesData">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="rule[value[0]]" ng-true-value="Y" ng-false-value="N">{{value[2]}}</label>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks  i used ishak dubey's way of doing that and also i am using your model method combined. But i am trying to access rules object though ng-model="rules" in my controller because i want to save rules which get checked and then property rules[1]=='Y' of unchecked rules changes to 'Y'. But i am not able to access rules object in my controller by scope variable i.e $scope.rule;

Comment: @SAJALMATHUR for that you have to do `ng-model='rule'` and then you will be able to access it in your controller as `$scope.rule` as i have edited my answer